# React Native Realm does not run on Android ( Task :realm:writeDebugAarMetadata FAILED )

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I am using Realm in my React Native project. I am developing on macOS and everything works great with iOS. However, on Android I get a build error ( see below ). I have tested with earlier commits where Realm was not yet there, everything executes well on Android in that case. `No AAR for react-native-reanimated found` can be ignored, the same issue appears on earlier commits and everything builds fine in the end.

Versions:

```
"react-native": "0.71.11",
"@realm/react": "^0.5.1",
"realm": "^11.10.1",
Android: API 33
```

Console:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/admin/dev_directory/smartphone-app/SmartphoneApp/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-android
warn Multiple Podfiles were found: ios/Podfile,vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/Podfile. Choosing ios/Podfile automatically. If you would like to select a different one, you can configure it via "project.ios.sourceDir". You can learn more about it here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source.
Android gradle plugin: 7.3.1
Gradle: 7.5.1
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Task :app:buildCodegenCLI SKIPPED
> Task :app:generateCodegenSchemaFromJavaScript SKIPPED
> Task :app:generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema SKIPPED
> Task :app:generatePackageList
> Task :app:preBuild
> Task :app:preDebugBuild
> Task :react-native-device-info:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-device-info:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-device-info:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:assertNoMultipleInstances
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:preBuild
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:preDebugBuild
> Task :react-native-reanimated:assertLatestReactNativeWithNewArchitectureTask SKIPPED
> Task :react-native-reanimated:assertNoMultipleInstances
> Task :react-native-reanimated:assertNoReanimated2WithNewArchitectureTask SKIPPED
> Task :react-native-reanimated:preBuild
> Task :react-native-reanimated:preDebugBuild
> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-screens:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-svg:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :realm:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :realm:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :realm:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-device-info:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-screens:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-svg:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :realm:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-device-info:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :realm:writeDebugAarMetadata FAILED
18 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 14 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':realm:writeDebugAarMetadata'.
> Failed to create parent directory '/Users/admin/dev_directory/smartphone-app/SmartphoneApp/node_modules/realm/react-native/android/build' when creating directory '/Users/admin/dev_directory/smartphone-app/SmartphoneApp/node_modules/realm/react-native/android/build/intermediates/aar_metadata/debug'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':realm:writeDebugAarMetadata'.
> Failed to create parent directory '/Users/admin/dev_directory/smartphone-app/SmartphoneApp/node_modules/realm/react-native/android/build' when creating directory '/Users/admin/dev_directory/smartphone-app/SmartphoneApp/node_modules/realm/react-native/android/build/intermediates/aar_metadata/debug'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

    at makeError (/Users/admin/dev_directory/smartphone-app/SmartphoneApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/admin/dev_directory/smartphone-app/SmartphoneApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/admin/dev_directory/smartphone-app/SmartphoneApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/admin/dev_directory/smartphone-app/SmartphoneApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Failed to create parent directory`sounds as permissions issue, but all permissions are fine. Read and write access granted. Tried `./gradlw clean`, did not help. After playing around and trying to fix things, I was getting one error after fixing another. At the end I have just deleted the project folder locally and cloned it from remote. I did not commit to Android and iOS folders on remote, they were clean initialised version ( when first creating react native project ). So during the build the React-Native source code along with dependencies were generated into clean android and ios folders. This helped and now everything works as a charm.

The problem is not caused by Realm, it was something local.

Answer (score 0):

`Failed to create parent directory`, Hmm it's seem permission problem, did u tried to move into Document folder?

Comment: It indeed sounds as permissions issue, but all permissions are fine. Read and write access granted. After playing around and trying to fix things, I was getting one error after fixing another. At the end I have just deleted the project folder locally and cloned it from remote. I did not commit to Android and iOS folders on remote, they were clean initialised version ( when first creating react native project ). So during the build the React-Native source code along with dependencies were generated into clean android and ios folder. This helped and now everything works as a charm.